# Android things DP6 Intent with android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS does not work anymore

Tags: android-things

I was using the intent with android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS to show the system settings screen from inside my app, to allow the user to configure certain details, like a bluetooth keyboard or adjust the timezone. This was working very well in the DP5.1.

But now in the DP6, the intent

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Does not work anymore. No exception is logged in the console.

Any workaround on this?

THe option to install the apk after configuring the device with the IOT_LAUNCHER screen is not very practical for me. Because I want to deliver an image with a bundle, and my app will be started automatically, not allowing the user to see the IOT_LAUUNCHER screen.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In DP6 the Settings application is either deprecated or removed. APIs to modify the screen or time [have been added](https://developer.android.com/things/sdk/apis/settings.html).

Comment: The apis have been added but I don't need to modify the screen. A need to provide a way for a user that flashes an image with my embedded apk, to configure the wifi connection. You can argue that the wifi connection can be configured when installing the image with the new setup utility, but this is only partially true. You have to know the ethernet ip of the device to configure it, and not all users will know it. 

I know that this is a DP, and I suppose that in the future there will be a way to give a user access to the system settings, but the previous version was not bad in this regard.

Comment: In the future, there will not be the expectation for a screen on these devices. Users would need to use different interaction models such as a companion app or segment display to provision their device. There's already APIs for Wi-Fi config that do not directly require a screen.

Comment: I have no wish to get involved in an argument, but I can not believe that the Android Things os will renounce to have an optional touch screen to control the Raspberry Pi or whatever. There are innumerable fields of implementation where a graphic UI for the app running on a android things device is essential.

Comment: And optional screen support will continue. However, in many production-ready devices, there will not be a screen, so there needs to be other ways to modify system settings.

Comment: @NickFelker It's not the greatest idea to remove the Settings Application. I have a case where I want to update the apk via the app itself. Since Android Things is running on Android Oreo it needs an extra permission for apps from unknown sources which can be granted from the Settings View. So it does not work anymore...

Comment: I don't seem like the greatest idea to remove functionality because other functionality is desired, what about the Settings application prevents other APIs from configuring the device? If you have that information it would be useful in this answer.